# Are all pictures are prohibited or only pictures with eyes?

Tags: halal-haram

My question is whether all pictures are prohibited or only the pictures that have eyes in them, like animal pictures with Eyes and without Eyes?

Comment: Pictures of living, animate moving beings is haram so pictures of humans, animals etc. Pictures of non-animate objects are allowed. They are buildings, cars etc.